# How is the z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2")) line in the names documentation read?

Tags: r, names

Referring to this example:

```
z <- list(a = 1, b = "c", c = 1:3)  
names(z)  
# change just the name of the third element.  
names(z)[3] <- "c2"  
z
```

The [names documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/names.html) says "*see the examples. This works because the expression there is evaluated as z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2")).*"

What is this final line of code about? It matches no R syntax that I'm familiar with, so I can't even fathom how to read it. If anything, it seems more complex than the example that it's trying to explain. How do I read it?

Comment: `names<-` is a different function which does the assignment

Comment: @akrun I understood that much, but `"names<-"` was a step too far for me.

Comment: If you type on the console. you will get ``names<-`
function (x, value)  .Primitive("names<-")#
names#
function (x)  .Primitive("names")`

Comment: There are some functions that have similar kind of assignment counterparts e.g. `substring`

Comment: Just remember that often when you have `funcname(leftside) <- rightside` that is actually calling `\`funcname<-\`(leftside, rightside)`

Comment: I used backquotes instead of double quotes as double quotes can be evaluated as string, while backquotes evaluates as is

Comment: @thelatemail I've found otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/q/65395373/10319707

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That part of the documentation is indeed badly written, I don't blame you for being confused.

Here is the short answer, say you have a vector `z = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)`, then the following are equivalent:

```
names(z)[3] <- "c2"
```

and

```
z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2"))
```

That's all the documentation is saying.

Here's the longer answer: in R you are probably familiar with the basic syntax of a function, so let's say you have `foo = function(x,y) x + y` then you are probably used to calling `foo(1, 2)`. You may also have seen 'infix' operators such as `+`, so you're probably familiar with `1 + 2`. However internally this is actually read as `"+"(1,2)` (try this it will work). A similar thing is seen with assignment and extraction functions, like `x[1]` (for some vector `x`) or as in this example `names(z)[3] <-`  where `<-` is the assignment operator.

To make this example even more complicated there's actually two separate infix operators being used! There's `names<-` and there's `[<-`, the first one is used to set the name of a vector and the second one is used to set a value in a vector after having first extracted the vector (I know there's a lot going on here).

So breaking down what that line is telling in more familiar R code:

```
z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2"))
```

1. `z`: Original vector
2. `y = names(z)`: Character vector - names of z.
3. `y[3]<-"c2"`: Extract the third element of `y` and assign it value "c2". Now we are at `"[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2")`.
4. `names(z)<-y`: Set the names of `z` as y. Now we are at `"names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2"))`.

Just to make things even more confusing `"names<-"` doesn't save the newly named vector, it just sets the new names. Which is why  `z <- "names<-"...` is required at the end to overwrite the original variable with the newly named one.

And showing this with R code:

```
> z = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
> print(z)
a b c 
1 2 3 
> names = names(z)
> names[3] = "c2"
> names(z) = names
> print(z)
 a  b c2 
 1  2  3
```

Comment: If `"[<-"` is assignment and extraction, then why doesn't `"[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2")` mean "take the third element of names(z) and assign to it "c2"?"

Comment: Using variables as examples: `x[y] <- z` is equivalent to `"[<-"(x,y,z)`. First argument is the vector to assign to, the second is the index of the element to change, third is the replacement value. So here we are saying: from the names of `z` replace the third value with "c2". Test this with: `'[<-'(letters, 1, "d")`

Comment: I think you've missed a step 5: the last `z <-` bit. It's probably also worth pointing out that `"[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2")` returns **all** of z's names.

Comment: I've improved the example (I hope)

Comment: So the thing to know about `names(z)<-` is that it doesn't actually just take a vector and change its names, what it does is: i) get the names; ii) change the names; iii) overwrite the original variable with the new names. This is a very subtle point in R coding and the only way to really understand it is to test it, just run the following and you'll see what I mean: `z = c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3); "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2"))`. You should be able to see that `"names<-"` doesn't actually save the result, so you have to overwrite `z`

Comment: I agree, I edited the answer after I wrote the comment. Happy your question is now answered. And also thanks for the challenge of explaining it.

Comment: I'm still not entirely comfortable with this. The suggestion that `"names<-"(x,y)` is not identical to `names(x)<-y` seems to run contrary to how inflix operators are supposed to work.

Comment: It is strange, I guess I haven't thought about it before. This is just true of all assignment operators in R, for example: `x = 1:2; "[<-"(x,1,3)`. I guess this is to do with copy-on-modify semantics?

Comment: I'll ask a new question about it.